# fgrep or egrep?

Tags: linux, string, shell, unix, grep

I have two files: usednaslist & naslist
Using RHEL5

**usednaslist**

> filera:/vol/EQIMS/build
>
> filera:/vol/iquad_dev/FAST_dev

**naslist**

> server12    SunOS   filera:/vol/EQIMS/build     /users/uxsrvlogs
>
> servers3    SunOS   filera:/vol/iquad_dev/FAST_dev      /mnt
>
> server4     SunOS   filerb:/vol/Security    /users/em_master

**Expected Output is**

> server4     SunOS   filerb:/vol/Security    /users/em_master

**What i have tried**

```
cat naslist | grep -vf usednaslist
```

No Output

```
cat naslist | egrep -vf usednaslist
```

No Output

```
cat naslist | fgrep -vf usednaslist
```

No Output

```
cat naslist | fgrep -xvf usednaslist
```

server12 SunOS filera:/vol/EQIMS/build /users/uxsrvlogs

servers3 SunOS filera:/vol/iquad_dev/FAST_dev /mnt

server4 SunOS filerb:/vol/Security /users/em_master

Comment: ??? what are you doing with the first file ? oO

Comment: I dont want to take this offtrack....basically if my export is in the usednaslist i dont want it to be printed when i cat through the naslist

Comment: Why are you using `cat`? Rather than `cat filename | grep ...`, just write `grep ... filename`. http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
grep -vf usednaslist naslist
```

`fgrep` is probably faster, you should just try it out ; )